# Replace a fragment defined in <fragment> container

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to replace a fragment defined in  by "android:name" which is a part of "activity_main" layout without success.

What I am doing wrong?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    rssFragment = RssFragment()
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fragment, "rssFragmentTag")

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.developer.myapplication.user_fragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix XML-declared `Fragment`s with `FragmentManager` replace/remove calls. See [Create a fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating#AddInLayout), specifically the note at the end:

> Note: When you add a fragment to an activity layout by defining the
>   fragment in the layout XML file, you cannot remove the fragment at
>   runtime. If you plan to swap your fragments in and out during user
>   interaction, you must add the fragment to the activity when the
>   activity first starts, as shown in Build a flexible UI.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace `<fragment>` that's already defined in your XML layout with another fragment, it will only attach the new fragment onto the layout of the existing fragment.

I believe you do not have any other choice but to replace your `<fragment>` with another `ViewGroup`, say:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"/>
```

And replace it with your existing call:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fragment, "rssFragmentTag")
```

Answer (score 0):

The commit transaction method is missing.

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fragment, "rssFragmentTag").commit()
```

Comment: Ah right, of course. But then if you commit a fragment this way it will end up attaching on the existing fragment.

Comment: @Aaron What you mean by "attaching"?